# CruiseControl.net 1.8.4 issues (with 2012 server)

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am running into a few issues with the latest version of CruiseControl on a new server 2012 box (iis 8). We had a previous version installed on an older machine with no problems, however the latest version is experiencing some strange issues.

--Running as a service and the service will fail to start. I've debugged the service it is getting a change notification that log4net.dll has changed and appears to attempt to restart the service before the service as fully started (throws a null pointer exception in StopRunner in CCService.cs)

--Webdashboard also gets a null pointer exception. The exception is from the ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.ASPNET.HttpHandler (first line), which perhaps indicates an issue with the session?

I've use CruiseControl.Net extensivily in the past, however is there some other configuration details I'm missing from the standard install?

**Edit**:

For the first issue, I ended up commenting out from CCServics.cs in the RunApplication method the section where the watcher was instantiated. The failure to start was not 100% repeatable. I was able to do builds, however the file change notification would also fire in the middle of building, which would stop the build from continuing. The file change notifications were on random files. However in all times, the files did not actually change.

Here is the stack trace for the webdashboard
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've got it running on 2012 R2 server.

What's different is that I had to install .Net 3.5 for sql server 2012,
and CCNet 1.8.4 also still requires .Net 3.5

Maybe that could help.

Can you provide a stacktrace?